# Inequality proof with AM-GM

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm new to this community. Do you think my solution is correct?
The problem is:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca\geq6, a+b+c=3$$

My solution:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca\geq3(ab+bc+ca)\rightarrow$$
$$3\geq ab+bc+ca$$

By AM-GM (1):
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 2(a+b+c)-3$$
By AM-GM:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca\geq2(a+b+c)-3+ab+bc+ca\geq2(a+b+c)-ab+bc+ca+ab+bc+ca=2(a+b+c)=6$$

Comment: Why the downvote? Please specify what could be done better to improve this post.

Comment: I didn't do any downvote, but I would expect a better way to present the problem.  Presumably you mean given $a+b+c=3$, we have to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca\ge6$.  If that was intended, it clearly is very different from what you have posted.  Further, I am not sure if you had any additional condition, like $a, b, c$ are positives.  Clearly writing the problem is the first step.

Comment: Further, in the last line of your solution, you have a mistake.  Ignoring the typos (presumably you wanted to replace $-3$ with $-ab-bc-ca$, but this is a reversal of $3\ge ab+bc+ca$, so this line (and approach) wouldn't work.

Comment: OH YEAS, i will try thank you @Macavity

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a+b+c=3$ is given, I would start with
$(a+b+c)^2=9 \iff a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=9-(ab+bc+ca)$, hence we are asked to prove
$$9-(ab+bc+ca)\ge 6$$
$$\iff 3\ge ab+bc+ca$$
for which you have already a valid proof.